# StoryBoardで配置したUICollectionViewのサイズ動的変更について

Tags: ios, swift

StoryBoard上にUICollectionViewを配置し、
サイズは、width:600,height:200で設定しました。

ViewControllerでは、@IBOutletでStoryBoard上のUICollectionViewと
紐付けてあります。
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

これをviewDidLoad()の時に、UICollectionViewのサイズを
width:600,height:100に動的に変更したいのですが、
反映されません。

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.collectionView.frame = CGRactMake(0, 0, 600, 100)
}
```

どうすればサイズを動的に変更できるでしょうか？
StoryBoardを使わないで、UICollectionViewを作れば
反映されそうですが、StoryBoardは使いたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewDidLayoutSubviews`でやれば反映されると思います。

参考：とりあえずいろいろ貼っておきます。
[AutoLayout使用時のviewのframe確定のタイミング](http://blog.xranker.info/blog/2014/01/27/autolayout/)
[UIViewControllerのライフサイクル](http://qiita.com/mo_to_44/items/0ca628b4cc74c8c5599d)
[メモリ管理・レイアウトの観点からみた UIViewController の view の扱い](http://blog.jarinosuke.com/entry/uiviewcontroller_view_coding_pattern)
[[iOS]viewDidLayoutSubviewsの最後にはlayoutSubviewsを呼び出そう](http://qiita.com/JunSuzukiJapan/items/81c3e6f6c02a99f94dd8)

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviewsで反映されました。
viewDidLoadでは、frameが確定していないことが、
教えていただいたリンクで参考になりました。